# rel attributte not working in this code

Tags: php, jquery

From this code i wrote in select query it will work fine,in database i have 10 number rows so it will come 10 comments,**for my problem is,i have one reply button while click the reply button i want get id,from here i got only first row id,i am clicking all button i got id=1**,i thing rel attribute it will make problem but i don't know exatly y? it is not working

```html
<?php
$comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_comments WHERE task_id='$task_id'");
while($com=mysql_fetch_assoc($comment)){
?>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img class="avatar" alt="" src="../TV/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="comment-block">
      <div class="comment-arrow"></div>
      <span class="comment-by">
        <strong><?php echo $com['comment_by'];?></strong>
        <span class="pull-right">
           <a href="#" rel="<?php echo $com['id']?>" class="reply-btn"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply</a>
        </span>
      </span>
      <p><?php echo $com['comment'];?></p>
      <span class="date pull-right"><?php echo $com['comment_on'];?></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>

  <!-- My JS code Like this -->

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.reply-btn').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        alert($(".reply-btn").attr("rel"));// here i got only first row id name like 1
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try $(this) to get the data from the clicked button. I would personally recoemmend using data attributes though. and probably suggest removing the spans from around the link anyway.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.reply-btn').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("rel"));// should give the the "rel" of the clicked button
        });
     });
```

Comment: In this code,what you are modified,i don't know what ur told

Comment: `$("this")` should not contain quotes. `$(this)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ya,i got it,now,Thanks @ Marcus

Comment: thanks @Marcus - answer amended - trouble with not focussing on what I was doing. Note that I got it right in the write up at the top of my post - just a small typo. Cheers. Gav

Comment: @yuvi - I simply swapped out the  ".reply-btn" class in the alert to $(this) - indicated by the text in my post. Using $(this) allows the getting of the reevent "rel" attribute from the clicked button .

Comment: You removed the `preventDefault()` method. I would recommend keeping that *as-is* to, well, prevent default behaviour when the user clicks the link (in this case appending `#` to the URL, and possibly *jumping* the user up the page). Put `event.preventDefault();` back in. If the link had a legitimate URL, in this case, once the `alert()` fired the user would then be taken to said URL, ie. `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" rel="<?php echo $com['id']?>" class="reply-btn">`

Comment: sorry @Marcus - that was not an intentional removal - just part of the same issue as before - not looking at what i was doing. I was only intending to do the $(this) swap.... I have replaced the removed content. Thanks mate